# angular 2 property binding concatenation without double quotes

Tags: angular

Hi my template is like the below

```
<a [href]="'http://sameet.com?id='+testId">
```

It returns the href link as http://sameet.com?id="12345" but i need to show http://sameet.com?id=12345

I have tried many ways like below

```
<a [href]="'http://sameet.com?id=' {{testId}}">
```

But it returns the same

Comment: The first snippet looks fine, to me. Are you sure the quotes are not coming from someplace else? Unless it's a typo, the `=` must be coming from someplace else.

Comment: @cartant Edited the question please check

Comment: First option should work

Comment: testId is string.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1vrEePwlA0evz58wPdhs?p=preview

Comment: You can also use `href="http://sameet.com?id={{testId}}"`

Comment: Thank you @yurzui it worked well it was the server responce with testId=""sampleid""

Comment: Just keep in mind if you are binding any variable then that time you dont need to use any kind of extra quotation with that Simply use {{<Your_variable>>}} and you are done

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should use like this in HTML

```
<a [href]="http://sameet.com?id={{testId}}">
```

And it will shows with link in browser http://sameet.com?id=12345